# Manually add files in $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to add manually files into $_FILES, then I use this method :

```
public function addToFiles($key, $filename): void {
   $tempName = tempnam('/tmp', 'php_files');
   $originalName = basename(parse_url($filename, PHP_URL_PATH));

   $rawData = file_get_contents($filename);
   file_put_contents($tempName, $rawData);
   $_FILES[$key]['name'][] = $originalName;
   $_FILES[$key]['type'][] = mime_content_type($tempName);
   $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'][] = $tempName;
   $_FILES[$key]['error'][] = 0;
   $_FILES[$key]['size'][] = strlen($rawData);
}
```

I see temporary file in temporary directory but `move_uploaded_file ()` return false.

What wrong with this code ?

Thank you

Comment: This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). You can't fake it out.